# Replace column conditional on matching in another column

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I would like to match two columns based on another. I'm trying to use the `match` function but gets NA values.

```
a <- data.frame( x =  c(1,2,3,4,5)) 
b <- data.frame( y =  c(3,4),
                 z = c("A","B"))

a$x <- b$z[match(a$x, b$y)]

I get:
> a
     x
1 <NA>
2 <NA>
3    A
4    B
5 <NA>
I would like :
> a
     x
1    1
2    2
3    A
4    B
5    5
```

Answer (score 1):

First, rename the numeric column of `b` so that you can merge the two data frames:

```
b <- b %>% rename(x = y)
```

Then, merge them, turn variables into character and replace the values of column `x` with those of `z` if not NA.

```
a <- merge(a, b, by = "x", all.x = TRUE) %>% 
  mutate_all(as.character) %>% 
  mutate(x = ifelse(is.na(z), x, z))
```

Result:

```
  x    z
1 1 <NA>
2 2 <NA>
3 A    A
4 B    B
5 5 <NA>
```

Answer (score 1):

Without renaming I would propose this which ends with the same result that `broti`

```
tmp.merge<- merge(a,b,by.x = "x", by.y="y", all = TRUE)
for (elm in as.numeric(row.names(tmp.merge[which(!is.na(tmp.merge$z)),]))){
  tmp.merge[elm,'x'] <- as.character(tmp.merge[elm,'z'])
}

tmp.merge
```

result :

```
> tmp.merge
  x    z
1 1 <NA>
2 2 <NA>
3 A    A
4 B    B
5 5 <NA>
```

Answer (score 1):

The following works but you need to set `stringsAsFactors = F`, when defining dataframe `b`

```
a <- data.frame( x =  c(1,2,3,4,10,13,12,11)) 
b <- data.frame( y =  c(10,12,13),
                 z = c("A","B","C"),stringsAsFactors = F)
#
a %>% mutate(x = ifelse(x %in% b$y,b$z[match(x,b$y)],x))
```

> Output

```
   x
1  1
2  2
3  3
4  4
5  A
6  C
7  B
8 11
```